# Why is my process taking higher resident memory as compared to virtual memory?

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, virtual-memory

'top' logs of my linux process show that its resident memory is around 6 times of the virtual memory. I have researched a lot but couldn't find any reason for such a behavior. Ideally VIRT is always higher than RES due to linux kernel's memory management. Top output is below -

```
13743 root 20 0 15.234g 0.010t 4372 R 13.4 4.0 7:43.41 q
```

Comment: Add the relevant portion of output of `top`

Comment: Question updated with output of top

Answer (score 0):

Not quite.

The `g` suffix indicates Gibibyte(s), and `t` indicates Tebibyte(s).

Let's do the conversion of `0.010t` to `g` (GiB):

```
zsh% print $((0.010 * 1024))g
10.24g
```

And `10.24g < 15.234g`, so yor assumption is not correct i.e. `top` is correctly showing the correct values for virtual set size (VSZ) and resident set size (RSS) -- just in different units (need to take a peek at the source for why).

Comment: Oh yes, thanks for pointing out! I misread the output. The numbers seem ok then.